# Cannot communicate with websocket. Autobahn: received HELLO message, and session is not yet established

Tags: javascript, django, python-3.x, websocket, autobahn

I am trying to build a WebSocket session using Python 3.4, Django, Autobahn and JS. I have successfully run the websocket server on the python side, but i cannot subscribe or receive any data published by the server

My code is fairly simple:

```
class TestAppWS(ApplicationSession):
    """
    An application component that publishes an event every second.
    """
    def onConnect(self):
        self.join(u"realm1")

    @asyncio.coroutine
    def onJoin(self, details):
        counter = 0
        while True:
            self.publish('com.myapp.topic1', counter)
            counter += 1
            yield from asyncio.sleep(1)


def start_ws():
    print("Running")
    session_factory = ApplicationSessionFactory()
    session_factory.session = TestAppWS
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)

    # factory = WebSocketServerFactory("ws://localhost:8090", debug=False)
    # factory.protocol = MyServerProtocol

    server = None
    try:
        transport_factory = WampWebSocketServerFactory(session_factory, debug_wamp=True)
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        coro = loop.create_server(transport_factory, 'localhost', 8090)
        server = loop.run_until_complete(coro)
        loop.run_forever()
    except OSError:
        print("WS server already running")
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
    finally:
        if server:
            server.close()
        loop.close()
```

start_ws() is run inside a separate Thread object. If I access localhost:8090 on my browser I can see the Autobahn welcome message.

On the frontend I have

```
var connection = new autobahn.Connection({
   url: 'ws://localhost:8090/',
   realm: 'realm1'}
);
connection.onopen = function (session) {    
   var received = 0;

   function onevent1(args) {
      console.log("Got event:", args[0]);
      received += 1;
      if (received > 5) {
         console.log("Closing ..");
         connection.close();
      }
   }

   session.subscribe('com.myapp.topic1', onevent1);
};

connection.open();
```

It does not seem to work, when I try to connect the frontend I get the following error on the backend side:

```
Failing WAMP-over-WebSocket transport: code = 1002, reason = 'WAMP Protocol Error (Received <class 'autobahn.wamp.message.Hello'> message, and session is not yet established)'
WAMP-over-WebSocket transport lost: wasClean = False, code = 1006, reason = 'connection was closed uncleanly (I failed the WebSocket connection by dropping the TCP connection)'
TX WAMP HELLO Message (realm = realm1, roles = [<autobahn.wamp.role.RolePublisherFeatures object at 0x04710270>, <autobahn.wamp.role.RoleSubscriberFeatures object at 0x047102B0>, <autobahn.wamp.role.RoleCallerFeatures object at 0x047102D0>, <autobahn.wamp.role.RoleCalleeFeatures object at 0x047102F0>], authmethods = None, authid = None)
RX WAMP HELLO Message (realm = realm1, roles = [<autobahn.wamp.role.RoleSubscriberFeatures object at 0x04710350>, <autobahn.wamp.role.RoleCallerFeatures object at 0x04710330>, <autobahn.wamp.role.RoleCalleeFeatures object at 0x04710390>, <autobahn.wamp.role.RolePublisherFeatures object at 0x04710370>], authmethods = None, authid = None)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\autobahn\wamp\websocket.py", line 91, in onMessage
    self._session.onMessage(msg)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\autobahn\wamp\protocol.py", line 429, in onMessage
    raise ProtocolError("Received {0} message, and session is not yet established".format(msg.__class__))
autobahn.wamp.exception.ProtocolError: Received <class 'autobahn.wamp.message.Hello'> message, and session is not yet established
```

on the javascript console I see:

```
Uncaught InvalidAccessError: Failed to execute 'close' on 'WebSocket': The code must be either 1000, or between 3000 and 4999. 1002 is neither.
```

Any idea? It looks like the session is not started, honestly it is not clear how this session work. Should not the session be initialized once a connection from the client is made?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `TestAppWs` and your browser code are both *WAMP application components*. Both of these need to connect to a WAMP **router**. Then they can talk freely to each other (as if there were no router in between .. transparently).

Here is how to run.

**Run a WAMP Router.**

Using [Crossbar.io](http://crossbar.io/) (but you can use [other WAMP routers](http://wamp.ws/implementations/#routers) as well), that's trivial. First install Crossbar.io:

```
pip install crossbar
```

> Crossbar.io (currently) runs on Python 2, but that's irrelevant as your app components can run on Python 3 or any other WAMP supported language/run-time. Think of Crossbar.io like a black-box, an external infrastructure, like a database system.

Then create and start a Crossbar.io default router:

```
cd $HOME
mkdir mynode
cd mynode
crossbar init
crossbar start
```

**Run your Python 3 / asyncio component**

```
import asyncio
from autobahn.asyncio.wamp import ApplicationSession


class MyComponent(ApplicationSession):

   @asyncio.coroutine
   def onJoin(self, details):
      print("session ready")

      counter = 0
      while True:
         self.publish('com.myapp.topic1', counter)
         counter += 1
         yield from asyncio.sleep(1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
   from autobahn.asyncio.wamp import ApplicationRunner

   runner = ApplicationRunner(url = "ws://localhost:8080/ws", realm = "realm1")
   runner.run(MyComponent)
```

**Run your browser component**

```
var connection = new autobahn.Connection({
   url: 'ws://localhost:8080/ws',
   realm: 'realm1'}
);

connection.onopen = function (session) {    
   var received = 0;

   function onevent1(args) {
      console.log("Got event:", args[0]);
      received += 1;
      if (received > 5) {
         console.log("Closing ..");
         connection.close();
      }
   }

   session.subscribe('com.myapp.topic1', onevent1);
};

connection.open();
```

Comment: Thanks oberstet, I had already spotted Crossbar.io over the internet but I thought I could implement it without an additional running node. I am trying to keep deployment simple. However it looks like I have no other choice :) I will try your solution

Comment: FWIW, we want to make deployment of Crossbar.io as simple as `yum/apt-get install crossbar`. A WAMP router should be a "blackbox" like an AMQP broker, not a library dependency in an app.

Comment: In the end I opted for the use of a parallel NodeJS for websockets. I think the idea behind Autobahn is good but I had issues because of crossbar. I use Python 3.4 and crossbar only runs on Python 2 that requires installing both python versions. Also crossbar full installation on Windows requires way too many packages. This makes the deployment a little bit too complex. An easy installation of crossbar would solve the issue but so far I find it too tricky.